# How to check if a bash script is executed inside or outside a vagrant machine?

Tags: bash, vagrant

I've a project with Vagrant. Sometimes I work from the Host. Some others I work from the Guest. I've a script that works only inside the Guest. I want to check if I am inside the vagrant machine, or outside, avoiding error messages. This is what I am doing:

```
if ! [ -d "/home/vagrant/project-folder" ]; then
    echo 'Cannot execute current script outside the vagrant';
    exit
fi;
```

There is another way to check if I am inside a vagrant machine than check if a folder exists?

Comment: There is no thing like a "vagrant machine". [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/index.html) is just a command line wrapper for several virtual machine engines.

Comment: you can test on the hostname, if you have set the hostname in your Vagrantfile, it will be easy to test your host hostname or the guest hostname

Comment: Or you can check the output of `lspci | grep VirtualBox` in case you are using it.

Comment: What is it about the guest that makes it suitable for your script to be run there? *That* is what you want to check for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an environmental variable passed to script:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "script.sh", env: {"IN_VAGRANT" => "true"}
```

Then in script:

```
if [-z "$IN_VAGRANT" ]; then
    echo 'Cannot execute the current script outside the vagrant';
    exit 1
fi
```

or maybe just check `logname`?

```
if [ `logname` = "vagrant" ]; then
    echo 'Cannot execute the current script outside the vagrant';
    exit 1
fi
```